# OpenLayers 3 street data

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers

I am able to manipulate coordinates, their position and diverse data. when testing I can see the street name on the map but i can't seem to find the data property to get.

What i am trying to do is simply get the street name based on my feature coordinates.

I logged the feature but i am can't find the data unless i missed it. I checked the [API](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/) too but there is nothing mentioning streets properties.

**UPDATE**

As suggested I used Nominatim reverse like this

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?format=json&lat=LAT&lon=LON&zoom=16
```

and through a simple `xhttp request` like this I got the response.

```
       var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
       }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
```

Source : [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp)

Note I am using v3.11 and OSM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong as I'm missing informations (e.g how your code look like) but if you think that because you can see street names on a map, you can access their properties, you are doing a mistake. If your background use `ol.source.OSM`, it's simply an image. You can't get street names from it.
If you want street names, you should better look at

- [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API), a webservice that returns vector data where you can get street names. You should start with [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) (an UI on top of Overpass API) to get started
- a reverse geocoder (it takes a point coordinates and return an adress) like [Nominatim](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/)

Comment: You can use Overpass API data in openlayers directly, see http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-osm.html. Not sure if this is already available in Openlayers 3.11.

Comment: thanks i will try something soon and try to get it work.